# WordPress have_posts() limiting number of posts retrieved

Tags: wordpress

I have the following code (inherited, I didn't write it) and I'm struggling to understand why it's only bringing back the 4 most recent posts instead of all of them.  That being said, I don't WANT all at once, but I want to be able to control how many come back.

Additionally, I'm going to need to write a function with a link at the bottom of this that says "Load more" and, when clicked, will bring back (via AJAX) the next four (or however many) posts to render immediately beneath the already displayed ones. How would I go about that?

Thanks!

```
        <?php if (have_posts()): ?>
        <div class="postSection">
            <?php
            while (have_posts()) : the_post();
                $pdf_download = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'pdf_download', true);
                $pdf_label = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'pdf_label', true);
                ?>
                <div class='postBox <?php foreach ((get_the_category()) as $cats) {
                    echo $cats->slug . ' ';
                } ?>'>
                    <div class="postImage">
                        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"
                           title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="postContent">
                        <h3><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"
                               title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
                        </h3>

                        <div class="postExcerpt">
                            <p><?php the_excerpt_rss(); ?>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a class="readMore"
                                                                               href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"
                                                                               title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>">Read
                                    More</a></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            <?php endwhile; ?>
        </div>
    <?php endif;
```

Comment: Generally that's a reading preferences setting.

Comment: AH! Thanks! I'll go check that out!

Comment: That being said, can I change that number depending on the page I'm on? For example, I only want the first four on the home page, but I want 6 on the landing pages of the various categories.

Comment: Figured it out. You can add `<?php query_posts('showposts=10'); ?>` (or if not 10, whatever) right before the code that  you want to bring back a non-standard amount.

Comment: **NEVER EVER** use `query_posts`, it break the main query objects, many plugins and custom code depends on the main query object.

Comment: Seems to be working fine on my site. Do you have a suggestion to accomplish what I'm looking to do in another way? I'm open to other ideas.